# How to link different (incompatible) libraries at runtime depending on program?

Tags: bash, gcc, bashrc, static-linking

I have a number of legacy codes that need to be compiled with specific (and often conflicting) libraries. To be specific I have a program which can only be compiled with `g77` and another program which can only be compiled with `gfortran`.

Let's call the first program [makee](http://spider.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/tab/makee/) and the second program [UVES_popler](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~mmurphy/UVES_popler).

When compiling (and running) they both need to be linked to the version of [pgplot](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot/) that is compiled with the respective compiler. So, compiling [makee](http://spider.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/tab/makee/) with g77 needs to run with [pgplot](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot/) that has been compiled by `g77` as well. And the same, respectively for [UVES_popler](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~mmurphy/UVES_popler) and `gfortran`.

Let's assume that I can compile pgplot with both g77 and gfortran -- what is the best practice for organizing my bashrc? Should I create a bash function for each program and have the proper links and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`s? Something like:

```
runmakee() {
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/g77-pgplot/
  makee
}
```

And (probably relatedly) is there a way of setting flags in Makefiles so that the proper libraries are called when compiling these programs respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bash functions should work, but the "usual" way of doing that is to write a wrapper script for each executable, and set anything that needs to be set in there. (You can change the executable name to `foo.bin` for instance, and call the wrapper script `foo` to make it easy to call.)

For ELF targets (not sure about other object formats), you can also set the `-rpath` linker option to hard-code a runtime library search path in your executables directly. With gcc (for C code), for the final link stage, it would look like:

```
gcc ... -Wl,-rpath,/your/hardcoded/path ...
```

I assume the Fortran compilers have similar options, or that you can change the linker options directly yourself (in which case the option is `-rpath /your/path`).